# Angular 4 JSON string to array

Tags: angular

Here is my code and if the console.log(data) in browser is

app.component.ts:34 [{"SemesterId":"Fall 2017"},{"SemesterId":"Spring 2017"}]

How can I convert this json string to an array and display it?
     this.result1=data['SemesterId']; doesn't work. Please take a look.

```
interface semester {
    SemesterId: string;

  }

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let h of result1">{{h}}</li>
  </ul>
`,
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

}

result1 :string;
r1:object;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:13043/students/courses/all').subscribe(
    data=>{
      this.result1=data['SemesterId'];
      console.log(data);
    }      
  )
  }

}
```

Comment: Correct fix:result1 :object; Then, this.result1=(JSON.parse(data.toString())). Everything works!

Answer (score 1):

change your service to

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:13043/students/courses/all').subscribe(
    data=>{
      this.result1=data;

    }      
  )
```

In your template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let h of result1">{{h.SemesterId}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.\n Cannot find a differ supporting object '[{"SemesterId":"Fall 2017"},{"SemesterId":"Spring 2017"}]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: change result1:string to result1:any[ ]

Comment: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to map your response as follow:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:13043/students/courses/all')
         .map((result) => result.json())
         .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Your endpoint is returning JSON string and you have to parse that into an object to use that in the way you want to.

You can also do it a different way, by calling:

```
this.result = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: It gives me an error. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.

Comment: How do you import Observable typings? Can you post your import statements from that file?

Comment: import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; And my angular version is 4.4.4

Comment: Try to change that to `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Yeah. I used rxjs, but it asked me to use Map. In addition, it said  Value of type 'MapConstructor' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?

Comment: The way you were importing is not including `map` I think, try to change your import to more general `rxjs`.

Comment: You can also try to additionally import that operator `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have found a better way. this.result=(JSON.parse(data.toString())). Which can convert the string to an object, then works fine with *ngFor.

Comment: Basically, that's the same as `result.json()`, I have updated my answer, so feel free to accept that if you found it useful.